# Duda con el uso del destructor C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dev-c++

Hola amigos de stackOverflow, estoy estudiando POO y me surgió el siguiente problema: Tengo una clase con dos atributos, uno de tipo string y otro de tipo int, cuando creo un objeto muestro sus datos en pantalla y luego llamo al destructor. Para confirmar la eliminación del objeto vuelvo a llamar el método para mostrar los datos del objeto y resulta que solo se elimina la información del string. No se si estoy omitiendo algo con el destructor o sencillamente lo estoy haciendo todo mal. Aquí el código:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Persona
{
public:
    Persona(string,int);
    ~Persona();
    void mostrarPersona();

private:
    string nombre;
    int edad;
};

Persona::Persona(string _nombre, int _edad)
{
    nombre = _nombre;
    edad = _edad;
}

Persona::~Persona()
{
}

void Persona::mostrarPersona()
{
    cout << "\tNombre: " << nombre << endl;
    cout << "\tEdad: " << edad << endl;
}

int main() {
    system("color 1F");

    Persona p1("Luis Miguel", 45);
    p1.mostrarPersona();

    p1.~Persona();

    p1.mostrarPersona();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando se llama al destructor de un objeto, es [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido) darle uso.

[El estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)<sup>1</sup> así lo especifica (la traducción y el resaltado son míos).

> #### 3.8 Ciclo de vida de objetos.
>
> La vida de un objeto de tipo `T` finaliza cuando:
>
> —(1.3) Si `T` es un objeto con un destructor no trivial. O
>
> —(1.4) **El espacio que el objeto cupa es reutilizado o liberado**.

> 4. Un programa puede finalizar la vida de un objeto al reutilizar el espacio que ocupa dicho objeto **o al llamar explícitamente al destructor de un objeto** con un destructor no trivial. Para objetos cuyo tipo tenga un destructor no trivial, no se requiere que el programa que llame al destructor explícitamente antes de que el espacio que ocupa el objeto sea reutilizado o liberado; sin embargo, si no hay llamada explícita al destructor o si una *expresión-delete* no es usada para liberar el espacio, el destructor no debe ser llamdao implícitamente y cualquier programa que dependa de los efectos secundarios provocados por el destructor tendrá comportamiento indefinido.

La redacción del estándar es muy confusa, pero viene a decir que cuando se ha acabado la vida de un objeto, ese objeto no debe usarse y si lo usas no se sabe lo que puede pasar.

> Resulta que solo se elimina la información del string.

El sub-objeto `Persona::nombre` de tipo `std::string` es un objeto con destructor. Al llamar al destructor de `Persona`, todos los destructores de todos sus sub-objetos se llaman en cascada. Una de las cosas que hace el destructor de `std::string` es eliminar la memoria que usa. En cambio, el sub-objeto `Persona::edad` de tipo `int` es un [tipo fundamental](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) y carece de destructor, el espacio que ocupa se marcará como "*disponible*" y podrá ser requerido por el sistema operativo cuando le plazca. Se muestra su valor anterior precisamente porque nadie ha reclamado ese espacio.

> Para confirmar la eliminación del objeto.

No tienes que confirmar nada, cuando un objeto es destruido tienes que olvidarte de que existe.

---

1. isocpp.org ha dejado de compartir gratuitamente borradores del estándar C++, el documento enlazado es borrador del estándar de 2014.

Answer (score 3):

Creo que tienes un malentendido con lo que significa *destruir* un objeto.

En C++, la *destrucción* de un objeto **solo implica la llamada a su destructor**. Es decir, **no implica absolutamente nada en lo relativo la gestión de sus propios recursos**.

Adicionalmente, C++ garantiza que, al llamar a un destructor, se llamará **de forma implícita** al destructor de sus variables-miembro.

En otras palabras: la destrucción de un objeto **no implica que se realicen cambios en la memoria**. Es un sistema a utilizar para liberar recursos (bloques de memoria, des-enlazarnos de posibles instancias relacionadas, ...).

Hay está la solución a tu duda: al destruir tu instancia, se llaman a los destructores de sus variables-miembro, a saber:

```
string nombre;
int edad;
```

La primera es un `std::string`, que **si** tiene un destructor *no-trivial* (dejamos esto para otra ocasión). Dicho destructor es invocado, y se realizan las tareas en el ubicadas. Concretamente, **libera la memoria usada por la `std::string`**.

A continuación tienes un `int`. Es un tipo *primitivo*, con un destructor *trivial*. En este caso, dicho destructor **se ignora**. Si bien a efectos teóricos puede considerarse que realmente es invocado, a efectos prácticos **no ocurre absolutamente nada**.

Y ya está. La memoria queda tal y como la dejaran los sucesivos destructores invocados. En el caso del `std::string`, deja constancia de que no tiene ningún bloque de memoria en uso (por eso te aparece como *vacía*). En el caso del `int`, no se hace absolutamente nada, y te aparece el último valor que tuvo.

Por cierto, llamar al destructor mas de una vez es un **comportamiento indefinido**, por lo que pueden ocurrir *cosas curiosas* ... Tenlo en cuenta para futuros experimentos :-)